# Google Apps Script: change value in cell while moving row to another tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I use to move rows (only selected columns) from one sheet to another depending on the value in a column in the first sheet. I'd like to find a way to convert the value in one of the columns of the "moving" rows before they get appended.

In the 5th column of the first sheet, the only possible values are "Good" or "Bad". When moving rows from the first sheet to the second one, I'd like to change "Good" to "1" and "Bad" to "-1".

For example, if the row I'm moving contains the values (col1= 11/12/2020, col2= test5@example.ex, col5= Bad) I'd like to paste those values in the second sheet as (col1= 11/12/2020, col2= test5@example.ex, col5= -1)

This is a test spreadsheet I created to give you a better understanding:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17CRkz71FehikIblgwjHg-r982cUe95WLPI6LiFUr2LI/edit?pli=1#gid=0

And this is the script I'm using:

```
//Move rows to Des tab from Form tab
function moveSafeRows()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Form');
  var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Des');
  var vals=rg0.getValues();
  for(var i=vals.length-1;i>0;i--)
  {
    if(vals[i][3]=='Yes')
    {
      sh1.appendRow([vals[i][0],vals[i][1],vals[i][4]]);
      sh0.deleteRow(i+1)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't vote on your question yet. I think that it was downvoted because it's not very clear what you are asking

Comment: Hi @Rubén, thank you for your comment. I'll try to clarify my question.

Comment: I think it's downvoted because your script shows no attempt at doing what you want it to do. You're basically asking for a feature and not a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
//Move rows to Des tab from Form tab
    function moveSafeRows()
    {
      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
      var sh0=ss.getSheetByName('Form');
      var rg0=sh0.getDataRange();
      var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Des');
      var vals=rg0.getValues();
      for(var i=vals.length-1;i>0;i--)
      {
        if(vals[i][3]=='Yes')
        {
          if(vals[i][4]=="Good"){
          sh1.appendRow([vals[i][0],vals[i][1],1]);
          }
          else{
         sh1.appendRow([vals[i][0],vals[i][1],-1]);
          }
          sh0.deleteRow(i+1)
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much, once again. I just started working with Google scripts and I was feeling a bit lost. Now that I see your answer it makes total sense. Thanks!